# Checking for missing values in CSV

Tags: python, csv, timestamp

I have a CSV file that counts the data in a timestamp every 15 min. 
I need tried to figure out how to see, if there is missing any of the 15 min in the file. But i cant get the code to work 100%.

hope you can help!

First i geathered the data from csv and set it in timestamp. The format is yyyy-mm-dd-hh:mm.

```
lst = list()

with open("CHFJPY15.csv", "r") as f:
    f_r = f.read()

sline = f_r.split()

for line in sline:
    parts = line.split(',')
    date = parts[0]
    time = parts[1]
    closeingtime = parts[5]

    timestamp = date + ' ' + time + ' ' + closeingtime
    lst.append(timestamp)

print(lst, "liste")
```

(All credits to BillBell for the code below)
Here try creating a consistently formatted list of data items.

```
from datetime import timedelta
interval = timedelta(minutes=15)
from datetime import datetime
current_time = datetime(2015,12,9,19,30)
data = []
omits = [3,5,9,11,17]
for i in range(20):
    current_time += interval

    if i in omits:
        continue
    data.append(current_time.strftime('%y.%m.%d.%H:%M')+' 123.456')
```

Now I read through the dates subtracting each from it predecessor. I set the first 'predecessor', which I call previous to now because that's bound to differ from the other dates.

I split each datum from the list into two, ignoring the second piece. Using strptime I turn strings into dates. Dates can be subtracted and the differences compared.

```
previous = datetime.now().strftime('%y.%m.%d.%H:%M')
first = True
for d in data:
    date_part, other = d.split(' ')
    if datetime.strptime(date_part, '%y.%m.%d.%H:%M') - datetime.strptime(previous, '%y.%m.%d.%H:%M') != interval:
        if not first:
            'unacceptable gap prior to ', date_part
        else:
            first = False
    previous = date_part
```

Hope you can see the problem.

Comment: You say you can't get it to work 100% - so what is it doing, and what is it failing to do?

Comment: You have included code and text from one of my answers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45654259/131187). It's *de rigueur* to credit authors here on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: sorry @BillBell yes of course i should credit you.

Comment: Thank you. Would you please indicate specifically what's going wrong?

Comment: Could you edit the question to show exactly what your CSV file looks like, i.e. 10 lines or so. And also show your expected output for that data.